# Use of AND logical operator in SUMIF formula

Tags: excel, logical-operators

Can anyone tell whats the syntax error in the following array formula? How can i use AND logical operator here with range and criteria in SUMIF formula? I am currently using Excel 2010.

```
SUMIF(C109:C923 & D109:D923 & I109: I923, C51&D51&I51, AU109:AU923)
```

Comment: It would be better if you can edit your question to show sample data in tabular form and expected results, so that any workaround on `SUMIF `function can be evaluated for its applicability to your situation.

Comment: put some more detail to get answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` is not a logical operator in Excel formulas. It is the text concatenation operator. `SUMIF` does not support concatenation of ranges. Thats why the error.

I suspect you are looking for [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b).

As of your formula try, I suspect:

```
=SUMIFS(AU109:AU923, C109:C923, C51, D109:D923, D51, I109: I923, I51)
```